# HTTP 500 error when logging in facebook on web or mobile

Tags: facebook, http, authentication, internal

I have been getting this error message the past 36 hours. Facebook support has not been any help at all when it comes to resolving this issue. I've cleared my cookies and cache multiple times. I've tried from multiple machines as well as my phone. Still no luck on logging in. Is it an error on my part or are they doing maintenance? Please assist, I did not want to have to post here but I have no more options...

The website cannot display the page 
 HTTP 500
   Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error.

What you can try: 
     Refresh the page.

```
 Go back to the previous page. 

 More information
```

This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying.

For more information about HTTP errors, see Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably something on their end. Responses with a 5xx status code are used when the server is aware it has erred in some way. More specifically, the 500 error has the [following definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1):

```
500 Internal Server Error:
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from 
fulfilling the request.
```

If the response had a 4xx status code, then the fault would lie on you. For example, if you made a request to a resource that doesn't exist, then you'd get a 404 response. As it stands now, something is wrong with their server.

Comment: Thats what I figured but is there anything I can do to fix it? Ive contacted them numerous times and they seem to have poor customer service.

Comment: Since it's their servers failing, you can't really do anything. You can check out their [API status here](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status/) to see if a service you depend on is failing (looks like the payment system is busted.) You could also go on their IRC channel at #facebook to ask for help. Good luck!

Comment: Not sure if that would help since they haven't replied to any email.  Pretty messed up.  I created a second acct but I need my old one back. Ive had it since like 06/07.

Comment: Still unable to access it and I'm on day 3. They are not responding to any of my emails, nor does it appear to be working any different. I have information and photos I need to access. I know my account is not removed/deleted because my friends can still see it.

Comment: Since it's an error on their side, you really can't do anything without their co-operation. I don't work for Facebook, so I can't compel them to help you either. Was your account ever deactivated? Was your account ever *deleted* (since you have two accounts, one might have been removed?) What's the URL you're trying to access by the way? I had a similar issue trying to access an old account with LinkedIn, and it took them a week just to respond to me. If they outsource their support, give it some time.

Comment: It was never deactivated or deleted. I created the second account after this started happening. I've tried the mobile site, ive tried normal www.facebook.com and ive tried the beta site. I will give it some time. In the mean time I'll remove my secondary account.

Comment: Problem just got fixed. They may have had an issue on one of their servers because of their new guideline policy. I posted something deemed as inappropriate and they removed the post, which is fine, but it made me click a few next buttons then I was back on. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. It appeared to be caused by this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1#asking-for-permissions

> Apps that ask for more than public_profile, email and user_friends must be reviewed by Facebook before they can be made available to the general public.

We were asking for more than the default, so I presume the 500 is caused by this lack of review.

It appears it can also happen if you haven't made your App public and try to login to it as anyone but you (the account that created the App).